# Salesforce Function fails to build on deploy

Tags: heroku, salesforce-functions

I'm trying to get Salesforce Functions working on my org, and seem stuck at the last step. I followed the docs (getting a compute environment + scratch org set up, etc) up until the deploy script.

Running `sf functions deploy` times out after an hour:
[image: deploy script]

Running `sf env log tail` results in:
[image: log tail]

This is using boilerplate default function code, and happens with all function languages (haven't tried python).

Any idea how to fix this, or how to view the heroku log file referenced? If it errored quickly, I would suspect an issue with the function's code, but because it times out I don't have any idea. Seems like an issue with on the s